# Node MCU failed to connect with firebase but does not return any error code

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, nodemcu

I need to send my data to firebase via NODE MCU. I've created an application that is used to turn on and off led in node mcu. My node mcu connects with the wifi network but does not send data to firebase. The `if(firebase.failed())` executes, but does not return an error code. In the serial monitor it just prints `setting/number failed:`. How can I fix this?

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "http://temphu*****.firebaseio.com/"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "VblTNS************OmWTW6n"
#define WIFI_SSID "A****"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "9*****"
#define LED 2

void setup() {
    pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED,0);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);    
    Serial.print("connecting");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("connected: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST,FIREBASE_AUTH);
    Firebase.setInt("LEDStatus",0);
}

void loop() {
    if(Firebase.getInt("LEDStatus")) {
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }
    if (Firebase.failed()) { // Check for errors 
        Serial.print("setting /number failed:");
        Serial.println(Firebase.error());
        return;
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source code it clearly says that (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/master/src/FirebaseError.h) two error codes are used in addition to regular HTTP error codes. Therefore Firebase rejection might not raise an error even though it fails.

So check the firebase rules and change read/write to true.